# $filter is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've created a filter for the cell data of `ui-grid`. I want to apply my custom filter with built-in currency filter of angular. Please find below my code:

```
var HelperServices = angular.module("HelperServices",['Constants']);
HelperServices.filter('getPriceFormat',function(){
    return function(val, $filter){          
            if(val == 0)
                return;
            else
                return ($filter('currency')(val, "", 7));           
            }
});
```

I am getting error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on return statement of `else` part.

**How do I make built-in filter working inside custom filter ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're injecting the `$filter` incorrectly, should be

```
HelperServices.filter('getPriceFormat',function($filter){
    return function(val){          
            if(val == 0)
                return;
            else
                return ($filter('currency')(val, "", 7));           
            }
});
```

Comment: If you to want minify/uglify your Angular with for example Gulp: use the annotation plugin to add the injections instead manually!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to inject the `$filter` service into your filter

```
filter('getPriceFormat',function($filter){
```

or better yet with inline array annotation...

```
filter('getPriceFormat', ['$filter', function($filter){
```